# How do I pass an object into a view via presentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

How do I pass data into a view controller that I'm presenting programmatically but have created in IB?  Right now I've got the code to pull up the view when the user clicks a button but am not clear how to send data along into that view.

I'm trying to use the code below but am being told that "Value of type UIViewController has no member "data""

```
@IBAction func showPossButton(sender: UIButton) {

    print("Show data table.")


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PossTable")
    var data:Data!
    vc.data = data

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PossTable") as! PossibleViewController` (or whatever the base class is for that scene).

Comment: That appears to have worked.  Can you explain the concept I'm missing for why I didn't know to do that or what that's doing?  Is it the idea that I need to point to both the scene in IB AND the view controller for xCode to be able to associate my data object with the right stuff?  And I was only pointing to the scene and not the view controller itself where I was trying to pick up the Data! object?

Comment: The concept is as follows: The `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method is defined to return a `UIViewController`. The compiler has no way of knowing what `UIViewController` subclass you happened to define in Interface Builder, so you have to tell it. So, yes, you have to tell IB what base class to use when instantiating the scene, and you have to tell the compiler what to cast this variable to, as well.

Comment: OK. I think I need to get a better understanding of "casting" in general as it's not yet intuitive to me that these UIViewControllers are all just variables, albeit fancy ones.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rob has mentioned, you must cast your instantiated view controller as the specific class that has the `data` field with `as! *insertViewControllerClassName*`

Answer (score 0):

`UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` returns `UIViewController` object. You have to cast this object to your ViewController.

Your method should looks like:

```
@IBAction func showPossButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Show data table.")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PossTable") as? PossTableViewController {
        var data: Data! = self.selectedData // Data from your parent VC
        vc.data = data
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("Can't cast view controller to PossTableViewController")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Rob has said in the comments:

> `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PossTabl‌​e") as! PossibleViewController` (or whatever the base class is for that scene)

Why?

This is due to something called *polymorphism*. It basically means that you can create variables like this:

```
let vc: UIViewController = SomeOtherViewController()
```

Although we all know that `vc` stores a `SomeOtherViewController` instance, the compiler only knows that it is of type `UIViewController`. As a result, we can't access the members of `SomeOtherViewController` through `vc`.

The `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is basically the same thing. It returns a value of type `UIViewController`. This causes the compiler to not know that it is actually a `PossibleViewController`. This is why it can't find the `data` property.

So to let the compiler know, you need to cast the return value to your desired type, since *you* know that it must contain an instance of `PossibleViewController`.